# FBConnect PHP Mysql Get Registered User to active session

Tags: php, mysql, fbconnect

The problem here is... Only registered user's can connect, if there's new user's it won't be able get the insert data to db. Please do assist. Thanks.

```
$app_id = "";
$app_secret = ""
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));
mysql_connect('localhost', '#', '#');
mysql_select_db('#');
# Let's see if we have an active session
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if(!empty($session)) {
    # Active session, let's try getting the user id (getUser()) and user info (api->   ('/me'))
    try{
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');   
    } catch (Exception $e){}
        # We have an active session, let's check if we have already registered the user
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE fbid = ". $user['id']);
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);     
    if($result['fbid'] = $_SESSION['id']) {      
        // this sets variables in the session 
        //$_SESSION['id'] = $result['fbid'];
        // $_SESSION['fullname'] = $result['fullname'];
        //$_SESSION['email'] = $result['email'];

        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
        header("Location: ".$login_url);
    }
}else if(!empty($user)){     
    # If not, let's add it to the database
    //}
    # We have an active session, let's check if we have already registered the user
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE fbid = ". $user['id']);
    $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    if(empty($result)){
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usertable (fbid, username, email) VALUES   ({$user['id']}, '{$user['username']}'");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_insert_id());
        $result2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        // this sets variables in the session 
        $_SESSION['id'] = $result2['id'];
        $_SESSION['fullname'] = $result2['fullname'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $result2['email'];
        //$_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];
    } else {
        # For testing purposes, if there was an error, let's kill the script
        die("There was an error.");
    }
} else {
    # There's no active session, let's generate one
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$login_url);
}
```

Comment: there's no semicolon at the end of the second line (`$app_secret = ""`)

Comment: Sorry I miss it out... it has a semi colon maybe omited when tryin' to remove the original app secret but still not getting the user's.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think anyone would help you with that question. It's too localized and I don't think people would try to understand this (pretty long) chunk of code to answer it. Furthermore, the code is very sloppy (eg. youre checking if `$result` variable is empty in a place where `$result` is undeclared). Try to work a little bit on this code and I'm sure you'll find the answer at your own. If not, try to generalize the problem and write a small but conceise piece of code to present it.

Comment: just solve it... thanks... working now.

Comment: No problem, congratulations. :)